# Assigning Value to Two Dimension Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to assign values to  a 2D array in VBA but its not working.
Here is what I have tried:

```
Sub UpdateCustomName()
    Dim CellTags() As String
    Dim temp() As String
    Dim ControlName As String
    Dim CellValue As String
    Dim CustomName(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As String

    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If Not Cell.Value = "" Then
            CellTags() = Split(Cell.Value, "*")
            ' here in CellTags(2) value is like ABC_E34
            CustomName() = Split(CellTags(2), "_")
            MsgBox CustomName(1, 2)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Dim CustomName(1 To 2)  As String is a 2D array ? I think CustomName(1 To 2,1 To 2) is 2D array

Comment: @Mailkov it says at cannot assign to array at this line CustomName() = Split(CellTags(2), "_")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub UpdateCustomName()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim CellTags() As String
    Dim temp() As String
    Dim ControlName As String
    Dim CellValue As String
    Dim CustomName(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As String

    For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If Not myCell.Value = "" Then
            CellTags() = Split(myCell.Value, "*")
            ' here in CellTags(2) value is like ABC_E34
            CustomName(1, 1) = Split(CellTags(2), "_")(0)
            CustomName(1, 2) = Split(CellTags(2), "_")(1)
            MsgBox CustomName(1, 2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

> If the cell contains value '**1*2*ABC_E34**' then:

[image]

> Info about 2D arrays in VBA:

http://www.homeandlearn.org/multidimensional_arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

Declare `CustomName` as a dynamic array instead:

```
Dim CustomName() As String
```

Note that `Split` returns a one-dimensional (not a two-dimensional) array. So `MsgBox CustomName(1, 2)` will not work. Instead, try, for example: `MsgBox CustomName(0) & " and " & CustomName(1)`

Comment: actually I want to save all controls names and cells in customName array like for each cell I will get some value like ABC_E44 I want to save these values for all cells in Custom name array by spliting them with "_"

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Please post a new question, and show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps.

Answer (score 1):

Split returns an array and I don't think you can set the value of an array to an array in VBA.  Does this help you at all?

```
Sub UpdateCustomName()
    Dim CellTags() As String
    Dim temp() As String
    Dim ControlName As String
    Dim CellValue As String
    Dim CustomName() As String
    Dim iCount As Long

    ' Redimension the array here, we cannot use a variable to dimension it in a Dim statement,
    'and it needs to be big enough to hold the data but not so big it wastes memory.
    ReDim CustomName(0 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count - 1, 0 To 1) As String

    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If Not Cell.Value = "" Then
            CellTags() = Split(Cell.Value, "*")
            CustomName(iCount, 0) = Split(CellTags(1), "_")(0)
            CustomName(iCount, 1) = Split(CellTags(1), "_")(1)
            MsgBox CustomName(iCount, 0) & " : " & CustomName(iCount, 1)
            iCount = iCount + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```